# Exclude password from sails user association

Tags: model, associations, sails.js, password-protection

In many of my object associations I refer the user model. How can I exclude the password field by default or by force.

E.g. `Post.findOne().populate('author')...` will yield the encrypted password of the author...!

**Edit 1** - 1 solution I found:

http://adityamukho.com/blog/tags/sails-js/ writes to override the toJSON method in the model:

`toJSON: function() {
            var obj = this.toObject();
            delete obj.password;
            return obj;
        },`

Answer (score 3):

See the waterline documentation:

https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models/instance-class-methods.md#toobjecttojson

Comment: Sweet! I originally put this too high in the model. Others should note this lives in the **_attributes_** section.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Waterline doc link: https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models/instance-class-methods.md#toobjecttojson.

The link Meeker posted 404's.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the documented way of deleting a user's password was not working.

I'm not sure why, but here's what I had to do instead:

```
attributes: {
    // Other attributes ...
    toJSON: function() {
      var obj = this.toObject();
      delete obj['password'];
      return obj;
    }
  }
```

For whatever reason, this works on my machine and the server I'm deploying to, but `delete obj.password` does not. I figured this may save someone a bit of hassle in the future.